# How to get specific record from ArrayList stored in fireabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored ArrayList in firebase DB, is there any way to get specific record from firebase using particular id (memberId) from `ArrayList`

Currently, I'm able to get the tripMemberList `ArrayList` but I want to get specific record from ArrayList using `memberId`

I don't want to retrieve full ArrayList only need a single record from `tripMemberList` using `memberId`

I'm attaching a firebase DB structure below
[image]

**Edit:** How i add a record to firebase

```
TripChatDTO tripChatDTO = new TripChatDTO();
tripChatDTO.setTripId(jsonObject.getInt("travelId"));
tripChatDTO.setTripName(travelDTO.getTitle());
tripChatDTO.setTripPicUrl(jsonObject.getString("image"));
List<TripMemberDTO> memberDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < invitedFriendArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = invitedFriendArray.getJSONObject(i);
    TripMemberDTO dto = new TripMemberDTO();
    dto.setMemberId(jsonObject1.getInt("id"));
    dto.setAdmin(false);
    dto.setNotification(true);
    memberDTOList.add(dto);
}
// Add Admin record
TripMemberDTO tripMemberDTO = new TripMemberDTO();
tripMemberDTO.setMemberId(loggedInUser.getId());
tripMemberDTO.setAdmin(true);
tripMemberDTO.setNotification(true);
memberDTOList.add(tripMemberDTO);
// Add all Member record to travel
tripChatDTO.setTripMemberList(memberDTOList);

String channelName = "Trip-" + tripChatDTO.getTripId();
// Create tip
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(TRIP).child(channelName).setValue(tripChatDTO);
```

Comment: You already have an Arraylist. Why do you need request from  Firebase?

Comment: @cricket_007 storeand get record both classes are deferent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it might be anywhere in the list I want to find a record using `memberId

Then loop over the children of the top element

```
tripMemberRef rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
   .child("Trips/Trip-190/tripMemberList");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot c : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String memberId =  c.child("memberId").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", memberId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: I don't want to get the complete list and loop over it because in future my list get 1000 of record

Comment: Firebase returns the entire list via the Snapshot. This is only an example. Please modify it yourself to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I'm able to get the specific record using query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Trips` is a direct child of the Firebase root, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Trips").child("Trip-190").child("tripMemberList").child("0");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String memberId = dataSnapshot.child("memberId").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", memberId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

But remember, Firebase is a NoSQL database which is structured as pairs of key and values. This means that every object within a Firebase database is a `Map` and not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know the index of the record `.child("0");` it might be anywhere in the list I want to find a record using `memberId'

Comment: @AkhileshPatil That isn't an index, it's a key

Comment: @cricket_007 I have stored a list and I don't know the key, in that particular list, only I have `memberId`

Comment: @AkhileshPatil We can't see the code how you added into the `tripMemberList`, but my point was that just look at the Firebase structure. It's 0..5, which are keys to the children. The number value is only a number, not really a positional index into the subtree of the element

Comment: @cricket_007 just a min I will update my code of how I add the list

Comment: If  you want to get all those childrens then, @cricket_007's answer is the right one. If you want just a particuklar one, use the code above. When you add a new memeber to `tripMemberList` store that value into a variable. After that you can use it in your `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: @AlexMamo you are right but I can't store that value to a variable because of both the screens deferent

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your help I'm able to get the specific record using query